# Excel remove document recovery pane?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, windows-registry

I tried a few registery tweaks but that doesnt seem to work. I use a batch script that switches between 2 excel sheets, but it forces closure of the excelsheet. This makes it so the Document recovery panel shows up.

Is there a way to remove the Document recovery panel in excel?

[image]

For anyone interested this is the batch script.

```
@ECHO OFF
:TOP
START excel.exe /r "\test1.xlsx"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 20
TASKKILL /F /IM excel.exe
START excel.exe /r "\test2.xlsx"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 20
TASKKILL /F /IM excel.exe
GOTO TOP
```

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what version of Excel you are using.

In Excel 2016 goto File then Options. Under Save there is a spot turn off AutoRecover "Save AutoRecover information every 10 minutes". If you uncheck that it will no longer function like you want. Or you can go further down and turn it off for just that document.
[image]

Comment: I tried this by disabling pretty much everything but it still shows the autorecover panel.